# How to change the System Volume programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I want to change the System's Volume. I am using following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace shaped_form
{
    class VolumeChange
    {
        private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
        private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 0xA0000;
        private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN = 0x90000;
        private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        private void btnMute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendMessageW(**this.Handle * *, WM_APPCOMMAND, **this.Handle * *, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE);
        }

        private void btnDecVol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendMessageW(**this.Handle * *, WM_APPCOMMAND, **this.Handle * *, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN);
        }

        private void btnIncVol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendMessageW(**this.Handle * *, WM_APPCOMMAND, **this.Handle * *, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
        }
    }
}
```

But I got an error at the highlighted places as `"shaped_form.VolumeChange does not contain a definition for Handle"`.

> I got this code from some internet sources.

Comment: Perhaps the class should extend the class Form? as in `class VolumeChange : Form`

Comment: Which Windows OS are you targeting?

Comment: @Patrick i'm not quite sure if that's what OP intends to do. it's still weird to have button click handlers outside a form class like this, so you might be right. +1

Comment: may i know the reason why you kept this question on hold

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting an error because `this.Handle` isn't defined in a plain vanilla class like that `VolumeChange` class you have there.
It comes from a `system.windows.forms` `form` class.

It needs to, because the `SendMessageW` method requires a *window handle*

Since you didn't define it in your new class, you can't use it.

Try passing a valid window handle in the constructor for `VolumeChange`, and using that to call `SendMessageW`

```
public class VolumeChange
{
  private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
  private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 0xA0000;
  private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN = 0x90000;
  private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;

  private IntPtr windowHandle;


  public VolumeChange(IntPtr hwnd)
  {
     windowHandle = hwnd;
  }

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr    lParam);
  private void btnMute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    SendMessageW(windowHandle, WM_APPCOMMAND, windowHandle,(IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE);
  }

  private void btnDecVol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    SendMessageW(windowHandle, WM_APPCOMMAND, windowHandle,(IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN);
  }

  private void btnIncVol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    SendMessageW(windowHandle, WM_APPCOMMAND,windowHandle,(IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
  }
}
```

If passing a window handle in the contructor isn't an option, (if you want to make `VolumeChange` static for instance)

Take a look at [GetActiveWindow (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646292(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer from Timothy, you should extract the class VolumeChange to its own class, and use it from your form button clicks. That way, if you want to change the volume from other forms or classes, you could to that as well.

Basically, you end up with two classes, your Form class and the utility class VolumeChanger. The Handle that you need is retreived when creating an instance of the VolumeChanger, via the form's [Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
public class VolumeChanger
{
    private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
    private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 0xA0000;
    private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN = 0x90000;
    private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;

    public VolumeChange(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        Handle = hwnd;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle { get; private set; }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public void Mute() {
        SendMessageW(Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, Handle, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE);
    }

    public void IncreaseVolume() {
        SendMessageW(Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, Handle, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
    }

    public void DecreaseVolume() {
        SendMessageW(Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, Handle, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN);
    }
}

public class Form1 : Form {

    private VolumeChanger _volume;
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        _volume = new VolumeChanger(Handle);
    }

    private void btnMute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _volume.Mute();
    }

    private void btnDecVol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _volume.DecreaseVolume();
    }

    private void btnIncVol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _volume.IncreaseVolume();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good addition, plus one.

Comment: just see this link  >http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104.aspx